# Query request: questions earning the popular question badge, but with no upvotes

Tags: discussion, data-analysis, data-explorer, popular-question

I recently noticed something odd. I had asked a [question on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/153492/tightvnc-and-vista-yields-vnc-server-closed-connection). I got one vote on an answer I later provided, but no votes on the question. Today, I log in and realize I somehow got the popular question badge on this question!(so, over 1,000 views!)

I'm requesting a query to see how many questions like this exist else where. If so, is this a problem we should worry about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is an issue.  Just because 1,000 people view a question, it doesn't mean it should have a lot of up votes.  It could be a question that looks good in the title, but once the read the rest they are no longer intrested.  In fact some "bad" questions (lots of negative votes) have high views.